# How to get all subNode 's value in XML file

Tags: c#

my XML is this form

```
<formatlist>
<format>
    <formatName>WHC format</formatName>
    <delCol>ID</delCol>
    <delCol>CDRID</delCol>
    <delCol>TGIN</delCol>
    <delCol>IPIn</delCol>
    <delCol>TGOUT</delCol>
    <delCol>IPOut</delCol>
</format>
<format>
    <formatName>Umobile format</formatName>
    <delCol>aaa</delCol>
    <delCol>bbb</delCol>
</format>
</formatlist>
```

if i only know formatName = WHC format and want to find all delCol include this format,that is ID,CDRID,....
How to do this using c#?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<formatList>...</formatList>");

var delCols = doc.Root
    .Elements("format")
    .First(e => e.Element("formatName").Value == "WHC format")
    .Elements("delCol")
    .Select(v => v.Value);
```

`delCols` will be an `IEnumerable<string>` you can use to get your values.